# Can I add a unique id attribute to a td from jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a table being populated and I would like the td id to be the id number for the data that was returned.  How do I assign an id to a td from jquery?

```
var $tr = $('<tr><td class="name"></td></tr>').insertAfter('#newTable tr:last');
$tr.find('.name').html(data.Name);
//How do I assign data.id to <td class="name"> ?
```

Comment: Just be aware that HTML IDs can not start with a number. Only a letter. So if your `data.id` does start with a number, you'll need to modify it. Maybe something like `"id_" + data.id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
$tr.find('.name').attr('id', data.id).html(data.Name);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.name').attr('id', data.id)
```

Comment: This will affect *all* `.name` elements currently on the page. :o)

Comment: sure. But my understanding of his question was "how to set the id of an element with JQuery".

Comment: Well, sort of. The question is how to set the ID of a specific element. If the OP was to run your code, *all* elements on the page that have the class `name` would get that ID. This isn't what the OP wanted, not to mention the fact that it would be invalid HTML since IDs must be unique. :o)